# When clicked on a link, start at a point on the webpage

Tags: html, web, anchor, href

I am building a website... Now I want the following:

I have a menubar with a dropdown. This dropdown has 4 options. All these 4 options are at one page. Now I want that when you click at for example the third option, you get redirected to the page where they all are, but that the third option is on top of your screen (so you cannot see the first and second option).

Can someone help me?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to provide code for this someone to actually help

Comment: theres no code needed to explain how that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand It good:

You want to make anchor links `<a></a>` that takes you to the other point of the same website.

It can be simply done by giving the point you want to redirect to an id, so e.g.:
(let's say you have everything about your work in this "work DIV" somewhere on the website and somewhere in the menu is the anchor tag with href to this "work DIV")...

```
<div id="work"></div>
```

and now you have some link in your menu with anchor tag that redirect you to this point:

```
<a href="#work">Redirect me to WORK</a>
```

First "#" in href means that you pointing to the id on the same page, because there's no path before that symbol.

Next in href is the name of your tag's id.

That's all I can do for you :) I hope I understood what you wanted.